# Is the average collision duration $\propto T^{1/2}/ P^2$?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, collision, action, kinetic-theory

### Question

So I was reading an [old question of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719817/does-a-constant-in-the-action-always-have-unobservable-consequences-in-classical) and realized the average collision duration $\langle \tau \rangle $ must be proportional to:

$$ \langle \tau \rangle \propto \frac{T^{1/2}}{P^2}$$

where $P$ is pressure and $T$ is temperature. Does my reasoning seem correct? Is this experimentally testable?

### Reasoning

> Consider the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L_M}$ for a gas. Generally in the gas ideal model only the kinetic energies are considered but let us think of the potential energy of a collision and not assume the collision is an event in spacetime but has finite duration. The turning point can be thought as a [consequence of regularisation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105668/150174).
>
> The [potential experienced](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/715450/150174) by $2$ objects when they collide is given by:
> $$ V_{exp} = \frac{1}{2} \mu v_{rel}^2 $$
>
> where $V_{exp}$ is the potential experienced, $\mu$ is the reduced mass and $v_{rel}$ is >the relative velocity. The new action density when collisions are included is given by:
>
> $$S(p) \to S(p) + S_c$$
>
> where $p$ is the momentum, $S(p)$ is the action when only kinetic energies are considered >and $S_c$ is the action contributed by the potential energy. Now, if I assume a short
> ranged interaction:
>
> $$ S_c = \int L_c dt \approx  V_{exp} \tau $$
> where $\tau$ is the collision duration.
> Now for a gas, the [number of collisions](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/06%3A_Modeling_Reaction_Kinetics/6.01%3A_Collision_Theory/6.1.04%3A_Collision_Frequency#:%7E:text=Collisional%20Frequency%20is%25%2020the%20average,time%20in%20a%20defined%20system) per $4$ volume is given by:
>
> $$ d N_c = \frac{1}{2}\rho^2 A |\langle v_{rel} \rangle | dt dx dy dz$$
> where  the $\rho$ is the density, $A$ is the area of the molecule and $dt$, $dx$, $dy$, $dz$ are infinitesimals.
> Hence, the action density $\tilde S_c$ for the entire gas is given by:
>
> $$ \tilde S_c  \approx \frac{1}{4} \rho^2 A |\langle v_{rel} \rangle |   \mu\langle  v_{rel}^2  \rangle \langle \tau \rangle  $$

Now if $\langle \tau \rangle$ was short range potential of any other form than:

$$ \langle \tau \rangle = \frac{C}{\rho^2 |\langle v_{rel} \rangle | \langle v^{2}_{rel} \rangle  } $$

(with $C$ being a constant) Then the equation of state would give rise to an unwanted observable consequence which are not observed in a gas in thermal equilibrium. Note:

$$ v_{rel} \propto \sqrt{T} $$

Comment: This doesn't look right: as $T$ increases processes generally speed up but the result suggests that the rate of collisions goes down?

Comment: But the collision duration is usually negligible are the some processes whose modelling require finite duration?

Comment: Isn't the typical Coulomb collision rate expressed as $\nu \propto n \ T^{-3/2}$, where $n$ is the number density and $T$ is the temperature (e.g., see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268594/59023)?